Porque mi funcion no se ejecuta, al estar trabajando con mensajes y estados de la api de meta "whatsappbussines"?
Estoy haciendo uso de la api de whatsapp para recibir y mandar mensajes, esto programado para que un bot responda, el hecho es que todo va bien cuando recibe el mensaje ya que lo prcesa y lo manda, el probleam viene cuando el hook recive el json de en donde trae el estatus de "delivery" ya que al estar tratandolo al final de eso me ejecuta un funcion en donde registro eso.
Estaba investigando y parece ser tema de asincrono ya que cuando recibe un menasje se libera el proceso y ejecuta esa funcion. Este es mi codigo
@app.route("/webhook/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def webhook_whatsapp():

if request.method == "GET":
    if request.args.get('hub.verify_token') == "":
        return request.args.get('hub.challenge')
    else:
        return "Error de Autenticación."

elif request.method == "POST":
    data = request.get_json()
    data_str = json.dumps(data)

    print(data_str)
    # with open('datos.json', 'a') as archivo:  # 'a' es para append (añadir al final del archivo)
    #     archivo.write(data_str + "\n")
    
    # Asegurándose de que messaging_product es 'whatsapp'
    try:
        entry = data['entry'][0]
        change = entry['changes'][0]
        value = change['value']
        messaging_product = value.get('messaging_product')
        phone_number_id = data["entry"][0]["changes"][0]["value"]["metadata"]["phone_number_id"]

        print(entry, change, value, messaging_product, phone_number_id)

        if messaging_product == "whatsapp":
            # Procesar estados de mensajes
            if 'statuses' in value:
                for status in value['statuses']:
                    if status.get('status') == "delivered":
                        recipient_id = status.get('recipient_id')
                        confirLlegadaMSG("entregado", recipient_id)
                        return jsonify({"status": "success"}), 200
            
            if 'statuses' in value:
                for status in value['statuses']:
                    if status.get('status') == "sent":
                        return jsonify({"status": "success"}), 200
            
            # Procesar mensajes entrantes
            if 'messages' in value:
                for message in value['messages']:
                    from_number = message.get('from')
                    text_body = message.get('text', {}).get('body')
                    if text_body:
                        cuenta_pClave = checkOmitir.obtener_nCuenta(text_body)

                        if cuenta_pClave.p_clave == "Csaldo":
                            consultar = checkOmitir.consulta_saldo(cuenta_pClave.n_cuenta)
                            enviar(phone_number_id, from_number, f'Tu adeudo {consultar._user_data["usuario"]} es de ${consultar._user_data["monto_adeudo"]}')
                            return jsonify({"status": "success"}, 200)  # RETORNAMOS EL STATUS EN UN JSON
                        
                        elif cuenta_pClave.p_clave == "Gfacura":
                            from datetime import date
                            fecha_actual = date.today()
                            consultar = checkOmitir.consulta_saldo(cuenta_pClave.n_cuenta)
                            generar_factura(consultar._user_data["usuario"], consultar._user_data["domicilio"], consultar._user_data["email"], from_number, fecha_actual, "exesos de tiempo", consultar._user_data["monto_adeudo"], consultar._user_data["cuenta"])
                            crear_y_mover_pdf(f'{consultar._user_data["cuenta"]}', f'./{consultar._user_data["cuenta"]}.pdf')

                            enviar_archivos(phone_number_id, from_number, consultar._user_data["cuenta"])
                            enviar_pdf(consultar._user_data["email"], "Consulta de Estado de Ceunta", f'./archivos/{consultar._user_data["cuenta"]}.pdf')
                            return jsonify({"status": "success"}, 200)  # RETORNAMOS EL STATUS EN UN JSON

                        else:
                            mss_bot = chat_bot(text_body)
                            enviar(phone_number_id, from_number, mss_bot.mss_final)
                            #enviar(phone_number_id, telefono_cliente, data_str)
                            return jsonify({"status": "success"}, 'mensaje bot enviado')  # Suponiendo que también quieres devolver un estado de éxito aquí
                        
                    return jsonify({"status": "success"}), 200

    except KeyError as e:
        return jsonify({"error": "KeyError - missing data in JSON"}), 400

    # Si no se encontraron ni 'statuses' ni 'messages' o 'messaging_product' no es 'whatsapp'
    return jsonify({"status": "no relevant data found or wrong product"}), 404

# Método no permitido
return jsonify({"error": "Method not allowed"}), 405

hasta ahora no e encontrado nada que me pueda ayudar
cualquier cosa o idea me ayudaria
